# SQL JOIN on Dynamic Column based on Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, vbscript, vb6

I have an image summary table [summary] that will serve as a reporting table in the near future. There is a reference table [views] and a third table that the image team populates [TeamImage]. The summary table has 1 row per part number (table has distinct part numbers) and many columns of image views (TOP, BOT, FRO, BAC, etc.). The [views] table lists each of these views with an id field, which is an IDENTITY field. The [TeamImage] table contains part numbers and views (part number field is not unique as the part numbers will be listed multiple times as they have image views).

Example:

```
    TABLE [summary]
Part_Number | TOP | BOT | FRO | BAC |
12345       |     |     |     |     |
67890       |     |     |     |     |

    TABLE [views]
id   | View |
1    | TOP  |
2    | BOT  |
3    | FRO  |
4    | BAC  |

    TABLE [TeamImage]
PartNum     | View |
12345       | TOP  |
12345       | BOT  |
12345       | FRO  |
12345       | BAC  |
67890       | FRO  |
67890       | BAC  |
```

Here's what I need in the end:

```
    TABLE [summary]
Part_Number | TOP | BOT | FRO | BAC |
12345       |  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |
67890       |     |     |  1  |  1  |
```

I could run several update queries but I have 27 views and about 2 million part numbers. I was hoping I could run something like below, even though I know I cannot use a variable as the column name:

```
DECLARE @id int = (SELECT max(id) FROM [views]), @ViewType nvarchar(3);

WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT @ViewType = (SELECT [View] FROM [views] WHERE id = @id);

    UPDATE a
    SET a.[@ViewType] = '1'
    FROM [summary] a
    INNER JOIN [TeamImage] b
    AND a.[Part_Number] = b.[PartNum]

    WHERE b.[View] = @ViewType;

SELECT @id = max(id) FROM [views] WHERE id < @id;

END;
```

Basically, I was hoping to use a variable to grab the different views from the [views] table (id = 27 down to id=1...could have counted up but doesn't matter) and populate the corresponding field in the [summary] table.

I know the SET a.[@ViewType] = '1' won't work, and a colleague of mine mentioned using VB but didn't know if that really was the most efficient option. I understand that I could use a PIVOT on the [TeamImage] table, but I'm not sure that will allow me to update my [summary] table (which has many more fields in it than just the image views). It still seems I need something that will effectively loop through update queries. I could write 4 update queries, one for each view (although my real table has 27 views), but I need something more dynamic in case we add views in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question a little better here: [SQL output as variable in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384237/sql-output-as-variable-in-vb-net) and was able to receive an answer that worked for what I was looking for. I appreciate DRapp providing a solution through PIVOT, but I think the VB way will be easier for me moving forward. In short, using VB with ExecuteScalar and ExecuteNonQuery, I was able to re-write my query using the variables I had above.

Answer (score 1):

To create your final summary, you can do via a simple pivot, yet this is fixed to the few codes you've done... but I know SQL does have a PIVOT command, but not directly familiar enough with it.

```
select
      TA.PartNum,
      max( case when TA.TeamImage = 'TOP' then '1' else ' ' end ) as TOPview,
      max( case when TA.TeamImage = 'BOT' then '1' else ' ' end ) as BOTview,
      max( case when TA.TeamImage = 'FRO' then '1' else ' ' end ) as FROview,
      max( case when TA.TeamImage = 'BAC' then '1' else ' ' end ) as BACview
   from
      TeamImage TA
   group by
      TA.PartNum
```

Obviously simple to expand, but you can also look into the "PIVOT" syntax

Comment: I appreciate the response and since I'm new to the PIVOT syntax in SQL, I will need to look into that, but I'm curious, will this be effective as an update or only on an initial filling of the table?

Comment: @rlphilli, Pivot tables are quite quick.  If you are trying to do an initial populate, then do regular updates to it, you can do a correlated update to keep in synch.  You could even do via triggers so when new records are added to your TeamImage table, it can automatically update the master summary view table.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I have a long ways to go in learning some best practices for SQL but if I can stay away from VB when I get the chance, I'm all for it.

Comment: That seems that it will only get me another summary table (not my [Summary] table, but I would still need to run update queries off of the PIVOTed table to update my [summary] table. That [summary] table has many more columns than just the image views and so a PIVOT that gives me just the view types will only help in that I can then run several update queries off of it, unless I'm missing something. It seems that this would be easier if I could write a VB script that could run the sql but instead of SET a.[@ViewType], could actually have the correct string sent to execute the SQL.

Comment: @rlphilli, you unchecked the answer, thats ok, but let me ask you.  You have 2+ million parts.  How many in your OTHER table of images... would that be something more like 30+ million for each image for the 2+ million items (not all have all images, so just 30+ million, not 54+ million).  You could build an update based on a trigger whenever any one image is inserted or removed from the images table to keep your master "views" table in synch...  Is that more what you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't mean anything from the uncheck except that I feel that the VB route is better suited for what i am looking for. I don't necessarily want a trigger that updates that table based on what another group does as we run nightly processes that check their tables before we run our update. I really do appreciate your responses and I need to work on the PIVOT more anyway as I see it can have great dividends in the future.

Comment: @rlphilli, As far as rebuilding, or putting into its own table, and you are running nightly,  you can just delete the table, then reselect the pivot via select (fields) into YourSummaryTable from (rest of query).