# SQL output as variable in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables

I cannot seem to figure out how to get an output of a SQL query as a variable in VB. I need something like what's below so that I can use that variable in another SQL query. SQL doesn't allow the use of variables as column headers when running queries, so I thought I could use VB to insert the actual output of one SQL task as the dynamic variable in a loop of update queries. Let me (hopefully) explain.

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @id int = (SELECT max(id) FROM [views]), @ViewType nvarchar(3);

WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    SELECT @ViewType = (SELECT [View] FROM [views] WHERE id = @id);

    UPDATE a
    SET a.[@ViewType] = '1'
    FROM [summary] a
    INNER JOIN [TeamImage] b
    ON a.[Part_Number] = b.[PartNum]

    WHERE b.[View] = @ViewType;

SELECT @id = max(id) FROM [views] WHERE id < @id;

END;
```

The SET a.[@ViewType] = '1' obviously will not work in SQL. But if I could have the (SELECT [View] FROM [views] WHERE id = @id) equal to a variable, then I could write the SQL query in VB and execute it and the variable would become part of the string and therefore execute correctly.

I'm newer to VB, but here's what I have so far:

```
Dim cn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server1;" & _
                                                 "Initial Catalog=DB1;" & _
                                                 "Integrated Security=SSPI")
cn.Open()

Dim cmd As New sqlCommand("SELECT max(id) FROM orientation_view_experiment;", cn)
vID = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Do While vID > 0
    Dim cmd2 As New sqlCommand("SELECT [View] FROM [views] WHERE id ='" + vID + "'"
    vViewType = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim cmd3 As New sqlCommand("UPDATE a
    SET a.'" + vViewType + "' = '1' & _
    FROM [summary] a & _
    INNER JOIN [TeamImage] b & _
    ON a.[Part_Number] = b.[PartNum] & _

    WHERE b.[View] = '" + vViewType + "';"
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
vID = vID - 1
Loop

cn.Close()
```

I hope some of that made sense, but I'm kind of lost at this point. I feel like I know what I need the SQL to do, but can't quite figure out how to make the computer/programs submit to my will and just do what I need it to do.

Thank you for any help/direction you can give.

Comment: That code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you insist in using `ExecuteNonQuery` for `SELECT` statements. `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't return the rows selected but just a count of the rows affected by an INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE query (I think that for SELECT it returns always zero)

What you need is [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to get the MAX value and the VIEW value because ExecuteScalar is the best choice when you expect to get just the first field of the first row from your SQL statement

```
Dim cmd As New sqlCommand("SELECT max(id) FROM orientation_view_experiment;", cn)
vID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

Do While vID > 0
    Dim cmd2 As New sqlCommand("SELECT [View] FROM [views] WHERE id =" + vID.ToString()
    Dim result = cmd2.ExecuteScalar()
    if Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) Then
       vViewType = result.ToString()

       Dim cmd3 As New sqlCommand("UPDATE a SET a.[" + vViewType + "] = '1' " & _
                                  "FROM [summary] a " & _
                                  "INNER JOIN [TeamImage] b " & _
                                  "ON a.[Part_Number] = b.[PartNum] " & _
                                  "WHERE b.[View] = @vType"
       cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vType", vViewType)
       cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
Loop
```

The last part of your code is not really clear to me, but you could use a couple of square brackets around the column name in table `summary` and a parameter for the View field in table `TeamImage`.

As a last advice, be sure that the column View in table TeamImage is not directly modifiable by your end user because a string concatenation like this could lead to a [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) attacks

Comment: Steve, I really appreciate you taking the time to edit the script to reflect the use of ExecuteScalar. I need to work through this as I'm not sure why you used the Parameter part at the end, when we didn't need it on the SET part, but I can read up on that. Also, the View column is not directly modifiable as we run validations as we import their data.

Comment: The parameter helps if the vViewType contains quotes or spaces or other characters not allowed in SQL. Using parameters is a best practice for passing any kind of values in sql commands. Too bad that a parameter cannot be used for column's name. In the SET before there is no risk of Sql Injection or parsing problems because we are sure to deal with an integer numeric value `MAX(ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Do a little research into what the different methods of a `command` are.  When you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, this return the *number of records effected*.  I think you want `ExecuteScalar` as your `cmd` and `cmd2` methods, so you can get a value from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing `'" + vViewType + "'` with `[" + vViewType + "]` ... in other words use square brackets to delimit the column name instead of single quotes which are for delimiting string literals?

Also, I would encourage stopping in the debugger, examining the command that you generated into cmd3 and try executing it directly. It might help you identify other similar problems such as the fact that vViewType is giving you a count of records instead of an actual value from the `[View]` column.